# Make specific x-axis labels for each facet_wrap graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am doing text analysis and trying to have graphs facet by year, but since the top 5 most frequent words for each year are different, the labels on the x-axis are ganna different. Is there any way that I can keep the specific labels under each graph instead of having one messy overall x-axis?

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  filter(president %in% c("George W. Bush", "Barack Obama")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = message)  %>% 
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word") %>%
  count(word) %>%
  arrange(-n) %>%
  slice(n=1:5)

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = reorder(word, n), y = n)) +
  geom_col() + 
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Word",
       y = "Count") +
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[output of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SetpB.png)
[output of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWmdt.png)

Comment: You could try using the `scales = "free_x"` option in `facet_wrap`

Comment: @AndrewGustar I don't the scales = 'free_x' will work in this context because the x-axis is a string, not an integer or double

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to lean on the `tidytext` library which has a function called `reorder_within()`. Here is an example of how that works. The font is small, but if you look close you will see the y-axis is different for each facet. You didn't include your dataset in the post. (You should do that by typing `dput(head(df))` and copying and pasting the output into your post so we can work with your version.)

```
mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec) %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 2:7) %>%
  mutate(car = tidytext::reorder_within(car, values, names)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values, y = reorder(car, values), color = names)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Mtcars", subtitle = "Dot Plot") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free')+
  theme(text = element_text(size=6)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Another option is to create graphs separately and put them together with `patchwork`.

```
one <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, origin, mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 4:8) %>%
  mutate(names = factor(names)) %>%
  mutate(values = as_factor(values)) %>%
  filter(names == 'am') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = '#e76254') + coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~names)
#
two <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, origin, mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 4:8) %>%
  mutate(names = factor(names)) %>%
  mutate(values = as_factor(values)) %>%
  filter(names == 'carb') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = values)) +
  labs(title = "Mtcars", subtitle = "Boxplot Panels") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = '#ef8a47') + coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~names)

three <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, origin, mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 4:8) %>%
  mutate(names = factor(names)) %>%
  mutate(values = as_factor(values)) %>%
  filter(names == 'cyl') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = '#f7aa58') + coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~names)

four <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, origin, mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 4:8) %>%
  mutate(names = factor(names)) %>%
  mutate(values = as_factor(values)) %>%
  filter(names == 'gear') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = '#ffd06f') + coord_flip() +
facet_wrap(~names)

five <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, origin, mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 4:8) %>%
  mutate(names = factor(names)) %>%
  mutate(values = as_factor(values)) %>%
  filter(names == 'vs') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = '#ffe6b7') + coord_flip() + `facet_wrap(~names)`

library(patchwork)
one + two + three + four + five
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an alternative to creating different plots? If I want to plot 10-20 facets then the patchwork solution requires a lot of code.